# Creating different size breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to scale my plot to have different size breaks. I have an equal number of breaks and I will be replacing them by numbers such as seen below, 1 = 15350018 etc. This is not producing a plot with labels nor the appropriately sized breaks. I have attached my script below and a subset of my data. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: This script works if the breaks are equivalent to the labels values. I don't know if that there is an issue with my logic in having breaks that are not the same size but I attempting to be scaled for a whole genome and I have seen this be done before in Manhattan plots (scatter plots).

**Script**

```
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = V5, y= V3, color = V4))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.35)+
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.35)+
  labs(title = "title", y = "ylab", x = "xlab")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
scale_x_discrete(
  breaks = c("15350018", "27289340", "41434118", "54204098")+
  labels = c("1", "", "3", "")
)
```

**Data**

```
01   3479816  .56  F  1
01   3598214  .25  F  1
02   6042448  .46  F  2
02   9000584  .12  F  2
03   9239154  .23  T  3
03   15049034 .76  T  3
03   18915079 .14  T  3
04   3590796  .12  F  4
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The sample code you give is not complete/does not run due to a missing final round bracket and an erroneous +. The plot it generates has no x axis labels. Can you provide a mock-up plot of what you want to do?

Comment: Something similar to this on the x-axis

https://bedford.io/projects/medium-data/images/epas1_manhattan_plot.png

Comment: I fixed the script. I had some things #-out that I was trying and didn't work. My mistake.

Comment: I am attempting to make the breaks be equal to the size of the chromosome. So each chromosome break would be scaled to its size, similar to the link I provided. I realized that break doesn't work the way I thought it would in this script though.

Comment: This link might be of some use to you: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Manhattan_plot_in_R.html